# How to load response at another tab

Tags: javascript, security, jquery, networking

i have colorbox which has a form which will be submitted to some other web site and i want that when the response which will come from that web page would loaded a new url should be opened in new tab

Comment: Please post some code. Did you try "_blank" or "someName" on the form?

Answer (score 0):

Use `target="_blank"` on your `<form>`.

Comment: _blank would open a new window each time. I found using a fixed name on the target useful from UX standpoint, since it would reload the same tab/window each time and not clutter the users desktop with lots of open windows.